# Integration of partial derivatives which are fractions

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, fractions

at the moment I seem to struggle with a problem, which I assume is more trivial than I think. The problem I'm facing is integrating partial derivatives in order to reconstruct a root function. For this, I found very helpful posts like

- [1]: [How to integrate a total derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537262/how-to-integrate-a-total-derivative)
- [2]: [Is it possible to reverse a gradient ($\vec{\nabla}$) operation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834607/is-it-possible-to-reverse-a-gradient-vec-nabla-operation/2025962#2025962)

I especially liked the [Ansatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2025962/784742) from one user of [2]. However, I cannot reconstruct the original function with the suggested methods, when one or more integrands appear in the denominator of one or more partial derivatives. One example:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A(x,y) &= \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 - y^2} \\ \\
\Leftrightarrow 
\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} &= - \frac{4 x y^{2}}{\left(x^{2} - y^{2}\right)^{2}} \\
\frac{\partial A}{\partial y} &= \frac{4 x^{2} y}{\left(x^{2} - y^{2}\right)^{2}} \\ \\
\Leftrightarrow
\int \frac{\partial A}{\partial x} dx &= \frac{2 y^{2}}{x^{2} - y^{2}} + h(y) \\
\int \frac{\partial A}{\partial y} dy &= \frac{2 x^{2}}{x^{2} - y^{2}} + g(x)
\end{aligned}
$$

The methods suggests to integrate one of the partial derivatives with respect to their derivative variable, assume an integration constant depending on the remaining derivative variable and look for missing parts. However, with the fraction structure, the terms always containt both variables. I'm clearly missing something out but I cannot see my mistake. Probably partial fraction decomposition might come in handy (though I don't see how).

Originally, I wanted to recalculate a derivation from Griffiths "[Exact Space-Times in Einstein's General Relativity](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511635397)" (2012) (p. 249), where two partial derivatives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\psi_{,y} &= \frac{y \left(x - 1\right) \left(x + 1\right)}{\left(x - y\right) \left(x + y\right) \left(p^{2} x^{2} + q^{2} y^{2} - 1\right)} \\ 
\psi_{,x} &= - \frac{x \left(y - 1\right) \left(y + 1\right)}{\left(x - y\right) \left(x + y\right) \left(p^{2} x^{2} + q^{2} y^{2} - 1\right)}\end{aligned}
$$

are defined ($p$ and $q$ fullfil $p^2 + q^2 = 1$, $\log m$ is the integration constant) with a short hint to their solution:

$$
e^{2 \psi} = m^2 \frac{p^2 x^2 + q^2 y^2 - 1}{x^2 - y^2}
$$

I hope I explained my problem as thoroughly as possible and I'm looking forward to your answers!

Best regards,
fwillo

Comment: Follow the methods described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809106/finding-the-scalar-potential-of-a-vector-valued-function, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182684/finding-potential-function-for-a-vector-field

Comment: Hello Hans, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I tried these methods already. Other posts referring to them are also listed in my post. The problem is more clear when showing the integration "constants" at the terms. In the example of integrating the $\partial / \partial x$ by $dx$, It seems senseless to look for more $y$'s when the $y$'s are already present.

Comment: No, you're not quite following the recommended steps. You should *not* integrate both partial derivatives separately and then try to piece the results together. You should integrate one of them, take the partial derivative of the result with respect to the other variable, and compare that to what it's supposed to be, in order to determine the “constant” of integration from the first step.

Comment: In your case, you ought to find that $h(y)=1$. (Or $g(x)=-1$, if you start from that end.)

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing this up Hans! I knew I had a twist in my thought. This question can be considered answered.