# $f_x = y^2$ and $f_y = x^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[Question from a Multivariable Calculus textbook]

Is there a function $f(x,y)$ with $f_x(x,y) = y^2$ and $f_y(x,y)=x^2$ ?

Couldn't come up with one. As integrating both partial derivatives separately yielded $f(x,y) = xy^2 + 2xy$  , and $f(x,y) = x^2y + 2xy$ . And it didn't seem possible to combine the two "branches" together into the same function.

Wondering whether anyone managed to come up with an example, or a definitive proof why such a function doesn't exist.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't there some extra assumption about $f$? Such as, for instance, being of class $C^2$?

Comment: Integrating both equations separately isn't the systematic way of approaching this kind of question (and you forgot to add the “constants of integration” which are actually functions in this case). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809407/1242) for the general procedure.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: That's automatic, since if there is such a function, then $f_x$ and $f_y$ are of class $C^\infty$ (they are assumed to be polynomials, after all), and hence $f \in C^\infty$ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Such a function cannot exist. That is, assume that a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ has partial derivatives $f_x(x,y) = y^2$ and $f_y(x,y) = x^2$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, for some functions $g, h$ on $\mathbb{R}$, we have $$xy^2+g(y) = f(x, y) = x^2y+h(x).$$
This gives us $g=h$ are both constants (hint: evaluate the above equation at $x=0$ and then instead at $y=0$). In particular, the equation now reads
$$xy^2 = x^2y.$$ But this clearly doesn't hold for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Hence, such an $f$ cannot exist.

A slightly slicker way: the first partial derivatives of $f$ are continuously differentiable. Hence, $f$ is twice continuously differentiable. So by the Frobenius Theorem,
$$2y = f_{xy} (x, y) = f_{yx} (x, y) = 2x.$$ This clearly doesn't hold in all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ either.